# Python - finding intersection between two lines on log-log plot

Tags: python

I have a rather simple problem (I think), but I cannot figure out where I go wrong.

I have two lines that I plot on a log-log scale in matplotlib. These two lines intersect and I need to know the point of intersection. So obviously I should set both lines equal to each other and then determine the x where they intersect. I use a formula to get there, but for some reason the intersection point is a little bit off.

This is the plot at normal size:
[image]

This is zoomed:
[image]

Complete code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_line(list_x, list_y, y1):
    
    # Range for plotting later
    range_x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
    
    # Function for the formula
    def func_exp(x, a, b):
        return (a * x)**b

    p0 = (0, min(list_x))
    list_line_info, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, list_x, list_y, maxfev=100000, p0=p0)
    
    # Both plot ranges to be used later
    plot_x = range_x
    plot_y = (list_line_info[0] * plot_x)**list_line_info[1]
    
    # Get intersection
    x = (abs(np.log10(y1)) / list_line_info[0])**(1 / list_line_info[1])
    
    return plot_x, plot_y, x

# Line 1
y1 = 0.03

# Line 2
list_x = [0.97614, 0.2948]
list_y = [0.06, 2.3]

plot_x, plot_y, x_intersect = create_line(list_x, list_y, y1)

# Plot
fig1, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)

ax1.plot(plot_x, plot_y)
ax1.plot([0, 1e1], [y1, y1], color='orange')
ax1.scatter(x_intersect, y1, color='red', zorder=2)

ax1.set_xscale('log', base=10)
ax1.set_yscale('log', base=10)

ax1.set_xlim(1e-1, 1e1)
ax1.set_ylim(1e-3, 1e3)
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try `x = (y1**(1 / list_line_info[1]))/list_line_info[0]`.

Comment: Yep that's it. Thanks a lot!